# How to upload images/file to Tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, file-upload

My current Spring boot application allows user to upload and retrieve images from designated directory when it is ran locally. But when I converted the application to jar file and run it on GCP everything went wrong. I get the following message:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: src/main/resources/static/avator/1593768592150Tf2UAh-1.jpeg
```

I have been searching for answers for a while and realized the file needs to be stored in the embedded Tomcat server instead of the resources directory from original application. But I can't find anything to help me achieve that or maybe I am on the wrong track? Please help me out and thank you in advance

Comment: You cannot do that. You can only store files in a physical location (which is why it works locally).

Comment: So you need another place to store the file, such as a database or another storage facility. Why does the path have `src` in it? That's a source directory, it shouldn't exist at runtime anyway.

Comment: My intention was to store the file path in the database and the actual file in a static folder like enginx. The frontend will retrieve the file path from API and load the image through the given file path from the static folder. So is that mean I should create a physical directory in GCP and have the actual image stored there?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to `application.properties`

`spring.resource.static-locations=file:<directory where you uploads images>`

Later the path is `http://<host>:<port>/<filename>` or `http://<host>:<port>/<directory>/<filename>` if uploaded file has additional directories then given in properties
I think it should let you solve your issue.

Comment: Then you can accept this question @AndyChang. (Tick on the left to the answer)